# Algorithm and IEEEtran

Tags: algorithms, ieeetran, pseudocode, algorithmicx

I'm trying to write an algorithm in a `IEEEtran` LaTeX template and it doesn't work in any way.

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmc}

%\begin{algorithm}[H]
\begin{algorithm*}
\caption{ASGP Merge and Pruning Step}
\label{alg:stuff}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\REQUIRE {$stuff$}
\STATE $stuff$
\RETURN $stuff$
\end{algorithmic}
%\end{algorithm}
\end{algorithm*}
```

but this is what I get:

> ! LaTeX Error: \begin{ALC@g} on input line 31 ended by \end{algorithmic}.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
>   Type  H   for immediate help.
>    ...
>
> l.47 \end{algorithmic}

I already tried use `\begin{figure*}` instead of `\begin{algorithm*}` but that
also doesn't work.

I saw a post about using `\begin{algpseudocode}`, but that isn't working either,
If I also `\include{algorithmic}`:

> ! LaTeX Error: Command \algorithmicindent already defined.
>                 Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

If not, I get:

> \REQUIRE undefined control sequence.

Can anybody help me with that?

Comment: It may just be a typo while posting, or it may be correct, but should the second line be `\usepackage{algorithmic}` rather than `\usepackage{algorithmc}`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `IEEEtran`'s documentation suggests:

> B. Algorithms
>
> IEEE publications use the `figure` environment to contain
>   `algorithms` that are not to be a part of the main text flow. Peter
>   Williams’ and Rogerio Brito’s `algorithmic.sty` package [24] or Szász
>   János’ `algorithmicx.sty` package [25] (the latter is designed to be
>   more customizable than the former) may be of help in producing
>   algorithm-like structures (although authors are of course free to use
>   whatever LaTeX commands they are most comfortable with in this
>   regard). However, do not use the floating `algorithm` environment of
>   `algorithm.sty` (also by Williams and Brito) or `algorithm2e.sty` (by
>   Christophe Fiorio) as the only floating structures IEEE uses are
>   `figure`s and `tables`. Furthermore, IEEEtran will not be in control of
>   the (non-IEEE) caption style produced by the `algorithm.sty` or
>   `algorithm2e.sty` float environments.

So, as suggested, do *not* use the `algorithm` floating environment; you can wrap your algorithm inside a `figure` (or `figure*`) environment (if a caption is required and the captions are to be `IEEEtran` compliant) and use the [algorithmicx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) package ; something like this:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
\State $r\gets a\bmod b$
\While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
\State $a\gets b$
\State $b\gets r$
\State $r\gets a\bmod b$
\EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
\State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Euclid's algorithm}\label{euclid}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If no caption is required, then simply don't use the `figure` environment.

Comment: Unfortunately this is so ugly compared to the algorithm environment

Comment: Here there is a better solution: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147598/how-to-use-the-algorithm2e-package-with-ieeetran-class From a question that Martin asked :)