# Algorithmic: file ended while scanning definition of \ALG\typeout

Tags: algorithmicx, algorithmic

I m trying to the given code given in here: [Algorithm and IEEEtran](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55883/algorithm-and-ieeetran), or some other examples.

by  `\usepackage{algpseudocode}`. But I am getting this error:

`./algpseudocode.sty:12: file ended while scanning definition of \ALG\typeout.`

I deleted the algorithm block, and only `\usepackage{algpseudocode}` gives the same error too. I think I have installed algorithm packes using texlive-science.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  That way those trying to help can focus on the solution as opposed to setting up the problem test case.

Comment: Well that does not compile as you have not provided a `\title`. But once you comment out the `\maketitle`, does the above code reproduce the problem for you? If so there is something wrong with your installation, as it compiles for me.

Comment: I had updated the code. So I have only problem when I include the algpseudocode. If I do not include algpseudocode, everything is fine. Also I put the algpseudoocode.sty from here: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/ . Still same.  Though you must be right, I think my package is broke somehow. I ll reinstall now.

Comment: I am not that knowledgeable with package installation, but think you should provide more information in your question as to what OS, are you using TeXLive, MiKTeX, what version, etc...  If by chance you are not on a current release I would recommend you upgrade to TeXLive2012, unless you have a reason to stick with an old release.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I upgraded to texlive2012 as you suggested and its solved now. Old release had been working fine for me, so I did not want to upgrade, also I would not think it could be the reason.

Comment: Glad you were able to get things resolved. Will vote to close this question as too localized then.