# How to use the algorithm2e package with IEEEtran class?

Tags: floats, algorithms, ieeetran, algorithm2e

The IEEEtran documentation suggests that I should not use the floating algorithm environment of **algorithm2e.sty**.

> B. Algorithms
>
> IEEE publications use the `figure` environment to contain
>   algorithms that are not to be a part of the main text flow. Peter
>   Williams’ and Rogerio Brito’s [`algorithmic.sty` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) or Szász
>   János’ [`algorithmicx.sty` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) (the latter is designed to be
>   more customizable than the former) may be of help in producing
>   algorithm-like structures (although authors are of course free to use
>   whatever LaTeX commands they are most comfortable with in this
>   regard). **However, do not use the floating `algorithm` environment of
>   `algorithm.sty` (also by Williams and Brito) or `algorithm2e.sty` (by
>   Christophe Fiorio) as the only floating structures IEEE uses are
>   figures and tables.** Furthermore, `IEEEtran` will not be in control of
>   the (non-IEEE) caption style produced by the `algorithm.sty` or
>   `algorithm2e.sty` float environments.

I tried using the suggested packages `algorithmic` and `algorithmicx` but I am not satisfied with the results and I would rather use the `algorithm2e` package.

A colleague told me that the suggestion of IEEE **applies only to the floating `algorithm` environment of the package and not to the package itself**. She suggested that I wrap the algorithm in a `figure` environment.

I tried to simply wrap the entire algorithm in a `figure`:

```
\documentclass[journal, a4paper]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[ruled,norelsize]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

%\begin{figure}[!t]

\begin{algorithm}[h]
 \caption{multiobjective DE} 
 initialize population $P = \left \{ X_{1}, ... , X_{N} \right \} $\;
 \For( \emph{Evolutionary loop}){$g := 1$ to $G_{max}$}
 {
    Do things \;
    Trim the population to size $N$ using nondominated sorting and diversity estimation \;
 }
\end{algorithm}

%\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But I get a

```
Not in outer par mode. \begin{algorithm}[h]
```

error. Obviously I cannot do it like this. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can follow this way.

First of all, you need to use the `H` specifier so to force the `algorithm` environment not to float.

Then, since the `H` specifier is not allowed in two-column mode, you can use the workaround described by Werner in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82272/27635), that is add the following lines in the preamble

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\removelatexerror}{\let\@latex@error\@gobble}
\makeatother
```

and issue the command `\removelatexerror` inside the `figure` environment.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[journal, a4paper]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[ruled,norelsize]{algorithm2e}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\removelatexerror}{\let\@latex@error\@gobble}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!t]
 \removelatexerror
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
   \caption{multiobjective DE}
   initialize population $P = \left \{ X_{1}, ... , X_{N} \right \} $\;
   \For( \emph{Evolutionary loop}){$g := 1$ to $G_{max}$}
   {
      Do things \;
      Trim the population to size $N$ using nondominated sorting and diversity estimation \;
   }
  \end{algorithm}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If you want, you can now even add a `\caption` to the `figure`, e.g.

```
\begin{figure}[!t]
 \caption{My algorithm}
 \removelatexerror
 ...
```

yields

[image]

Comment: Ideally one would like to redefine `algorithm` to do all of this error removal and `figure` placement automatically, so you can just use `\begin{algorithm}[t]`...`\end{algorithm}`.

Comment: @Werner As it is, one can add a `\caption` to the `figure`, too.

Comment: @karlkoeller Perfect! Exactly what I needed

Comment: @MartinDrozdik Glat it helped.

Comment: This works greatly and preserves the standard algorithm style, great! Thank's a lot! Also, note that to have the caption below the algorithm, the `\caption{...}` command must be placed at the bottom, near `\end{figure}`.