# How to place an algorithm inside of a Table and reference that Table?

Tags: tables, hyperref, cross-referencing, captions, algorithm2e

Right now I have an algorithm and I wish to reference it throughout a body of text.

However, the way that the algorithm is being reference is awkward. See top figure. Using `\autoref`, the algorithm is reference simply as "algorithm 1". I wish instead to reference a table that contain algorithm 1, and refer to readers to look at the table instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{thmtools}       

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

{\LinesNumberedHidden
    \begin{algorithm}
        \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
        \SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
        \SetAlgorithmName{Algorithm}{} 

        Initialize: $x^0$ = 0;
        \begin{enumerate}   
            \item Pour hot coal on $f(x)$
            \item Freeze coal until $\|f(x)\|_\infty < \epsilon$
        \end{enumerate}

        \caption{Meta-Coal Algorithm}
        \label{algo:Coal Meta-Heuristic}
\end{algorithm}}

Look at my beautiful algorithm in \autoref{algo:Coal Meta-Heuristic}

\end{document}
```

Instead, I want something like this:

[image]

Now I am referring the algorithm that is CONTAINED in a table, I feel referencing this table more natural this way. The table's name could go on top of the algorithm or at the bottom (as currently shown). The caption for that table could be called something like "Description of Meta Coal algorithm" or just "Meta Coal algorithm" (as currently shown).

However, if I try to place the algorithm block inside of a `\begin{table}` the entire thing fails to compile!

```
\begin{table}
{\LinesNumberedHidden
    \begin{algorithm}
        \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
        \SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
        \SetAlgorithmName{Algorithm}{} 

        Initialize: $x^0$ = 0;
        \begin{enumerate}   
            \item Pour hot coal on $f(x)$
            \item Freeze coal until $\|f(x)\|_\infty < \epsilon$
        \end{enumerate}

        \caption{Meta-Coal Algorithm}
        \label{algo:Coal Meta-Heuristic}
\end{algorithm}}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Does anyone know if there is a way to accomplish what I want with minimal effort?

Comment: Well, you're trying to nest a float in a float...

Comment: Please don't use spaces in label names -- it is possible of course, but can break if further processing of the label name is required.

Comment: A shorter solution is `\caption{Meta-Coal Algorithm}\refstepcounter{table}` The label will then use the table counter information

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks but I'm still interested on getting that Table caption working i.e. Table 1 - Description of MC algorithm.

Comment: `\usepackage{caption}` and `\captionof{table}{Description of ...}` perhaps?

Comment: Why not writing ".. my beautiful  algorithm1"?

Comment: @Guido: ... because that's too easy? ;-)

Comment: Its my master's wish

Comment: @MachineLearningisnotGod: I have added the `\captionof` solution as well to my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `H` specifier so the algorithm is not more a floating object and can be put inside a table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

\begin{table}
{\LinesNumberedHidden
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
        \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
        \SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
        \SetAlgorithmName{Algorithm}{}

        Initialize: $x^0$ = 0;
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Pour hot coal on $f(x)$
            \item Freeze coal until $\|f(x)\|_\infty < \epsilon$
        \end{enumerate}
\caption{Meta-Coal Algorithm}
\end{algorithm}}
\caption{Meta-Coal Algorithm}
\label{algo:Coal Meta-Heuristic}
\end{table}

Look at my beautiful algorithm in \autoref{algo:Coal Meta-Heuristic}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great solution. But unfortunately im using IEEEtrans and [H] is not allowed in two column mode

Comment: @MachineLearningisnotGod Take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147598/80972

Comment: Thanks! I have realized that Figure is also a suitable way to encapsulate the algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

**See an alternate solution with `\captionof` at the end of this post.**

I suggest to use `cleveref` and its `\label[othercountername]{...}` feature and `\Cref{...}` or `\cref{...}` instead, i.e.

`\label[table]{yourlabelname}`

Nesting floats in floats is nasty and does not work anyway.

If the name of the referenced counter should appear in the link provided by `\Cref` or `\cref` use `\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}`.

Please load `cleveref` after `hyperref`!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{thmtools}       

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

{\LinesNumberedHidden
    \begin{algorithm}
        \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
        \SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
        \SetAlgorithmName{Algorithm}{} 

        Initialize: $x^0$ = 0;
        \begin{enumerate}   
            \item Pour hot coal on $f(x)$
            \item Freeze coal until $\|f(x)\|_\infty < \epsilon$
        \end{enumerate}
        \caption{Meta-Coal Algorithm}
        \label[table]{algo:CoalMeta-Heuristic}
\end{algorithm}}

Look at my beautiful algorithm in \Cref{algo:CoalMeta-Heuristic}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternate solution with `\captionof` from `caption` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{thmtools}       

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

{\LinesNumberedHidden
    \begin{algorithm}
        \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
        \SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
        \SetAlgorithmName{Algorithm}{} 

        Initialize: $x^0$ = 0;
        \begin{enumerate}   
            \item Pour hot coal on $f(x)$
            \item Freeze coal until $\|f(x)\|_\infty < \epsilon$
        \end{enumerate}
        \captionof{table}{Meta-Coal Algorithm}
        \label{algo:CoalMeta-Heuristic}
\end{algorithm}}

Look at my beautiful algorithm in \autoref{algo:CoalMeta-Heuristic}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please note that this might confuse readers anyway. The 'Algorithm' is still listed in the list of algorithms, but it is not listed in the LoT!