# Using algorithm2e in figure environment

Tags: floats, ieeetran, algorithm2e

I am using algorithm2e to explain my algorithm and surrounding it within float environment for IEEETran class as suggested in [How to use the algorithm2e package with IEEEtran class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147598/how-to-use-the-algorithm2e-package-with-ieeetran-class)

Below is a sample code:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[plain, vlined, linesnumbered, noresetcount]{algorithm2e}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\removelatexerror}{\let\@latex@error\@gobble}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \removelatexerror
        \begin{algorithm}[H]
            \textbf{struct} Node \{ \\
            \Indp
            \textbf{Int} key;\\
            Node* child[2];\\
            \Indm
            \}; \\      
        \end{algorithm}
        \hrule
        \captionsetup{justification=centering}
        \caption{Node structure}
        \label{alg:NodeStructure}
    \end{figure}

    Figure \ref{alg:NodeStructure} represents a node in our tree
\end{document}
```

After I compile this code, I see a significant gap between the text and my algorithm. Is there any way to reduce this gap.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is not particular to [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e), but more so to do with the natural gaps between floats and the surrounding text as laid out by the [class](http://ctan.org/pkg/IEEEtran). [Here is a quick view on the lengths involved in the separation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/layouts/layman.pdf):

[image]

The default lengths for `IEEEtran` are

- `\floatsep`: `0.85\baselineskip plus  0.2\baselineskip minus  0.2\baselineskip`
- `\textfloatsep`: `1.55\baselineskip plus  0.2\baselineskip minus  0.4\baselineskip`
- `\intextsep`: `0.85\baselineskip plus 0.2\baselineskip minus  0.2\baselineskip`

These are all fairly large, but allow for some manoeuvring within a two-column layout (due to the `plus` and `minus`). Here's the view with `\textfloatsep` set to `0pt`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[plain, vlined, linesnumbered, noresetcount]{algorithm2e}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\removelatexerror}{\let\@latex@error\@gobble}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \removelatexerror
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \textbf{struct} Node \{ \\
    \Indp
    \textbf{Int} key;\\
    Node* child[2];\\
    \Indm
    \};
  \end{algorithm}
  \hrule
  \caption{Node structure}
\end{figure}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In finibus est in pulvinar semper. 
Nullam a mauris nibh. Aliquam egestas quam at vulputate condimentum. Suspendisse quis velit eros.

\newpage

\setlength{\textfloatsep}{0pt}

\begin{figure}
  \removelatexerror
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \textbf{struct} Node \{ \\
    \Indp
    \textbf{Int} key;\\
    Node* child[2];\\
    \Indm
    \};
  \end{algorithm}
  \hrule
  \caption{Node structure}
\end{figure}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In finibus est in pulvinar semper. 
Nullam a mauris nibh. Aliquam egestas quam at vulputate condimentum. Suspendisse quis velit eros.

\end{document}
```