# How to use the algorithmic package with IEEEtran class?

Tags: ieeetran, algorithm2e, algorithmicx, algpseudocode

I found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147598/how-to-use-the-algorithm2e-package-with-ieeetran-class) explaining how to use `algorithm2e` package with IEEEtran class. However I would like to be able also to use the `algorithmic` package.

For the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[!t]
 \removelatexerror
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \begin{algorithmic}
     \For( \emph{Evolutionary loop}){$g := 1$ to $G_{max}$}
     {
        \State Do things \;
        \State Trim the population to size $N$ using nondominated sorting and diversity estimation \;
     }
    \end{algorithmic}
  \end{algorithm}
\end{figure}
```

I am getting an error:

```
ERROR: You can't use `\prevdepth' in horizontal mode.

--- TeX said ---
\nointerlineskip ->\prevdepth 
                              -\@m \p@
```

I am reusing preamble from the original question:

```
\usepackage[ruled,norelsize]{algorithm2e}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\removelatexerror}{\let\@latex@error\@gobble}
\makeatother
\usepackage{algpseudocode,algorithmicx}
```

I would highly appreciate if you could help me to fix the problem.

**UPD** Full minimal example:

```
\documentclass[journal, a4paper]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[ruled,norelsize]{algorithm2e}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\removelatexerror}{\let\@latex@error\@gobble}
\makeatother
\usepackage{algpseudocode,algorithmicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!t]
 \removelatexerror
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \begin{algorithmic}
      \For{\texttt{<some condition>}}
        \State \texttt{<do stuff>}
      \EndFor
    \end{algorithmic}
  \end{algorithm}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, add a full (but minimal) example from `\documentclass` up to `\end{document}`.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Ok I updated it again because the definition of for loop was wrong in  `algorithmic` environment.

Comment: You shouldn't use `algorithm2e` together with `algpseudocode`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `algpseudocode` package is not compatible with `algorithm2e`.

```
\documentclass[journal, a4paper]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}

\begin{algorithmic}
  \For{\texttt{<some condition>}}
    \State \texttt{<do stuff>}
  \EndFor
\end{algorithmic}

\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```